# How to refresh previous activity ToolBar menu (Cart) value

Tags: android, menu, refresh, toolbar

I am having 2 activity. 1st activity has the toolbar menu as Cart.And the value is increased or decreased depends on cart count. The next activity fragmnet has the Cart Functionality.Here we can remove the cart product.

Let us consider  the images:

1. Image 1 has the cart count as 3.
2. Cart Functionality page has the count as 3.
3. Now I remove the first product.
4. In the respective page it is deducted from previous value.
5. But while I come to the first activity it is not refreshed, instead of 2, it has the 3 as cart count.

How to refresh a first activity while I use onBackpressed the second activity.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: take preference in your second activity and take value in sharedpreference pass it into first activity and update your cart in your first activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved it by using `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();           /*-------Cart Basket with Counter---------*/
    mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    CommonUtil.dbUtil.open();
    MainFragmentAdapter.CART_COUNT = String.valueOf(CommonUtil.dbUtil.getCartItem().getCount());
    MainActivity.mCounter.setText(MainFragmentAdapter.CART_COUNT);

    invalidateOptionsMenu();

    badgeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Config.menuItemClicked = true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("cart_Clicked", Config.menuItemClicked);
            editor.apply();
            Intent next = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
            startActivity(next);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In First Activity 's `onRestart` method check cart item count(like its increase or decrease) call `onPrepareOptionmenu` method to update count(make sure your count updated before come to first activity). you have to maintain tempcount and actual count. Hope you understand!

Comment: Thank you @Dhawal Sodha Parmar

Answer (score 1):

You can get activity reference by ((YourHomeActivity)getActivity()) in fragment class. Make your toolbar variable public and access it via activity reference to updatr it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is Use Sharepreference to store value of cart so it will make change all activity and put code in onResume() method